# How to get details of editor of SharePoint site file?

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-rest-api, odata, webhooks

I am working on SharePoint notifications using webhooks. I tried the following POST request.

```
https://xxxxx.sharepoint.com/_api/SP.AppContextSite(@target)/web/lists('2c955ea0-28h4-4f84-a8b5-001df9be12b')/getitembyid(93)?@target='https://xxxxx.sharepoint.com/sites/yyy'
```

I am getting the following response:

```
<d:ContentTypeId>0x0101007C119F47C066B746A51B6B65706817AZ</d:ContentTypeId>
        <d:ComplianceAssetId m:null="true" />
        <d:Title m:null="true" />
        <d:SharedWithUsersId m:null="true" />
        <d:SharedWithDetails m:null="true" />
        <d:ID m:type="Edm.Int32">93</d:ID>
        <d:Created m:type="Edm.DateTime">2020-02-03T13:35:24Z</d:Created>
        <d:AuthorId m:type="Edm.Int32">15</d:AuthorId>
        <d:Modified m:type="Edm.DateTime">2020-02-04T04:39:19Z</d:Modified>
        <d:EditorId m:type="Edm.Int32">17</d:EditorId>
        <d:OData__CopySource m:null="true" />
        <d:CheckoutUserId m:null="true" />
        <d:OData__UIVersionString>13.0</d:OData__UIVersionString>
        <d:GUID m:type="Edm.Guid">10c64759-2e1c-47ce-9985-2e394b6a59bb</d:GUID>
    </m:properties>
</content>
```

Is there any way to get editor detail using editor ID?

Answer (score 3):

Try using below endpoint:

```
/_api/SP.AppContextSite(<host web url>)/web/lists('2c955ea0-28h4-4f84-a8b5-001df9be12b')/getitembyid(93)?$select=Title,Editor/ID,Editor/Title&$expand=Editor
```

**OR**:

**Get a user from a site by id**:

```
/_api/SP.AppContextSite(@target)/web/getuserbyid(16)?@target='<host web url>'
```

Where `16` is user ID.

**Get a user from a site by login name**:

```
/_api/SP.AppContextSite(@target)/web/siteusers(@v)?@v='i%3A0%23.f%7Cmembership%7Cuser%40domain.onmicrosoft.com'&@target='<host web url>'
```

**Source**: [User resource - Supported HTTP methods](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/developer/sharepoint-rest-reference/dn531432(v=office.15)?redirectedfrom=MSDN#supported-http-methods-7).

Answer (score 2):

You can use the below rest on success of your request in the question using the EditorId.

```
/_api/SP.AppContextSite(@target)/web/getuserbyid(EditorId)?@target='<host web url>'
```